# Starting an executable program that uses additional libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, allegro

I made a program with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. It uses additional libraries (Allegro), and it runs perfectly from MSVC, but I can't run it from it's directory. (...\"project name"\Debug\"project name".exe) It writes that it can't find some kind of .dll files.

That's not good, because I want to make it work for everyone! What to do to make it work?

I know that I have to put the necesarry .dll files, but I don't know where?

Comment: Either put the DLL files in the `%PATH%`, or add the path to the DLL files to the `%PATH%`, or put the DLL files together with the executable.

Comment: There was only one necessary dll so it was easy. But I didn't know that I had to put to that place. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an executable is started, Windows searches the current directory, the `PATH` and then some other places. The exact description can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You need to make sure either the PATH includes the library you need, or place it in the same directory (or in some other automatically searced directory, but that's typically not a good solution).

Comment: You can also write a batch file that wraps the executable and sets the proper `PATH` for the application first.

Comment: There was only one necessary dll. Thank you anyway!

Comment: THe `PATH` is an environment variable. In a command prompt, you can see it with `echo %PATH%` - you can set it in the control panel, but I don't have my Windows machine up and running at present, so I can't give you precise steps. Here's an example I found with Google, you will need to modify some of the details, but the overall process is the same: http://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/AddingPythonToWindowsPath

Comment: I see. No problem, I can get it. Thanks!